# LayerSwitcher in OpenLayers 8.2.0?

Tags: openlayers, layers

I was surprised to read that the latest version of OpenLayers (ie. 8.2.0) does not have a layer switcher control as in the earlier versions.

After googling it seems that such a control has been nicely provided by a third party, but up to version OL 6 (if I am right).

Can you point to additional working options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last OpenLayers version that had native layer switcher control was 2.13.1 (see web archive at https://web.archive.org/web/20200701183524/http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher-js.html). With version 3.0 native layer switcher control disappeared from OpenLayers (see all controls in v3 docs at https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.control.html).

Maybe there exists, but I could not find any explanation/justification anywhere on [OpenLayers GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) for omission of layer switcher.

But already with version 3 and up to the latest 8.2.0 there is [ol-layerswicher](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher#readme) plugin from Matt Walker available that works just fine.